# Is it possible to make such an image with Tikz? How?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-pic

I'm wondering what's the best way to render this image width the dashed line and with angles between normal lines and dashed lines. And also Is there a way to quickly rotate the tikz resulting image 90 degrees without rotating the letters?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90]`

Comment: Also, it could be made better (arcs in your figure are pretty much horrible).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Incomplet" but I think you can finish it. There are only basic stuff (without calculation) so you can use only tikz. It's possible to rotate the picture but you need to place the drawing in a scope and then redefine the labels.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/O,0/5/M,3/5/I,3/10/S,0/10/y,3/3.5/J}
\tkzDrawSegments(O,M M,I I,S M,y O,I)
\tkzDrawSegments[dashed](O,S I,J)
\tkzDrawPoint[size=12](M)

\tkzLabelPoints[right](I,S) \tkzLabelPoints[left](M,O)
\tkzLabelSegment[left](O,M){$D_d$} \tkzLabelSegment[right](I,S){$D_{ds}$}
\tkzLabelSegment[left,pos=.75](O,S){$D_S$}
\tkzLabelSegment[above,pos=.4](M,I){$\zeta$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=2](S,O,M) \tkzLabelAngle[pos=2.3](S,O,M){$\beta$}
\tkzMarkAngle[size=3](I,O,M) \tkzLabelAngle[pos=3.3](I,O,S){$\theta$}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That zeta should be a xi.

Comment: for sure but OP can correct this himself ! :)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your result is fantastic. Short, clear and with a very nice result. I owe you a beer/coffe!