# Can anyone please help with a drawing in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can anyone of you please help me how to do this figure in TikZ? :)

[image]

Comment: look at this : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299457/is-it-possible-to-make-such-an-image-with-tikz-how

Answer (score 2):

On the first sight the sketch is quite simple, however if you like to exploit capabilities of TikZ, you should have some experiences with it (regardles, you have on SE solution for similar graphs) ...

See, if the MWE below fulfill your expectation:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               preview]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,intersections,quotes}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
           > = stealth,
angle radius = 7mm,
   MA/.style = {% My Angle
        draw, <->,
        angle eccentricity=1.3}, % angle label position!
        font=\small\sffamily
                        ]
% coordinate origin
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
% coordinate axis
\draw[name path=A] (-2,0) -- ++ (6,0) coordinate (a);
\draw (0,-2) -- ++ (0,4);
% line
\draw[name path=B]  (-0.5,-2) coordinate (b) -- ++ 
                    ( 4.0, 4) coordinate (c);
% intersection
\coordinate[name intersections={of=A and B, by=X}];
% angle `\alpha`
\pic[MA,"$\alpha$"] {angle = a--X--c};
% perpendicular line
\draw[gray] (O) -- node[above right,inner sep=1pt] {$p>0$} 
            ($(b)!(O)!(c)$) coordinate (d);
% perpendicular angle sign
\draw[gray] ($(d)!2mm!(O)$)    coordinate (e) -- 
            ($(e)!2mm!90:(d)$) coordinate (f) --
            ($(b)!(f)!(c)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]